# Selecting strings in between two sets of characters in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need to select a string between two sets of characters in PowerShell and could use some help. I have some csv data and one of the columns contains a string that I need to select a portion of to populate two other columns. I've got one of these done but need help with the other 
This is what my text looks like:

```
My-Computer-IneedthisABC1234567
YourComputer-IneedthistooABC9876543
```

Basically I need the numerical portion and the `ABC` portion will always be the same so I'm retrieving with the number with the following:

```
($Computer.nickname -split "ABC")[0]
```

I'm stuck on how to retrieve the `Ineedthis`and `Ineedthistoo` part. It will always come in between  `-` and `ABC`

I suspect a Regex is the way to go with this but I'm just not sure where to start with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a really hackish way would be:

```
$var = ($Computer.nickname -split "ABC")[0] 
$var.split('-')[-1]
```

or simply:

```
(($Computer.nickname -split "ABC")[0]).split('-')[-1]
```

that would split on `-` and get last element

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Much appreciated.